# Prove $x+y^\alpha z^{1-\alpha}\le (x+y)^\alpha(x+z)^{1-\alpha}$ for $x,y,z\ge 0$ and $0<\alpha<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

I wish to prove the inequality $$x+y^\alpha z^{1-\alpha}\le (x+y)^\alpha (x+z)^{1-\alpha}$$ for $x,y,z\ge 0$ real numbers, and $0<\alpha<1$. Clearly this holds when $x,y$ or $z$ are $0$, but I can't manage to prove this simply by differentiating. What other techniques are there that would allow me to prove this inequality?

Comment: from where Comes this inequality?

Comment: It comes from an exercise in Evans, 5.3, where we're meant to find an interpolation bound for a Holder norm, which we derive from an easy interpolation result on the seminorm. Essentially, $x=\lVert u\rVert_{C^0}$, $y=[u]_{C^{0,\beta}}$, and $z=[u]_{C^{0,1}}$, then from the fact that $$[u]_{C^{0,\gamma}}\le [u]_{C^{0,\beta}}^{\frac{1-\gamma}{1-\beta}} [u]_{C^{0,1}}^{\frac{\gamma-\beta}{1-\beta}}$$ we're meant to determine that
$$\lVert u\rVert_{C^{0,\gamma}}\le\lVert u\rVert_{C^{0,\beta}}^{\frac{1-\gamma}{1-\beta}} \lVert u\rVert_{C^{0,1}}^{\frac{\gamma-\beta}{1-\beta}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $u=(x^{\alpha},y^{\alpha})$ and $v=(x^{1-\alpha},z^{1-\alpha})$, then $u\cdot v\leq\|u\|_{1/\alpha}\|v\|_{1/(1-\alpha)}$. Simplifying this, the result follows.